# USB devices don't get detected

Tags: 13.10, usb

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10. My USB ports don't detect USB devices connected to them. When you connect and disconnect anything to/from USB ports and monitor with `lsusb` nothing changes. Every now and then, when I reboot, it suddenly works. Then it stops working again after another reboot.

I tried to watch `dmesg` while plugging in a USB device and unplugging it, nothing changes either. I used `sudo watch 'dmesg'`, also `sudo tailf /var/log/dmesg`.

Answer (score -1):

you can try installing DISK Utility from :https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/
.Then open Disk-> select the usb device ->go to the gear icon and turn auto mount option on.

Comment: the problem is not with mounting. The devices just don't show up, also, when I even monitor lsusb and I didn't say storage devices, I said, usb devices. That means, for exmple, how do you mount a usb mouse :). Any usb device doesn't get detected, although, when I plugin a telephone, for example, it doesn't get detected, but can be charged.

Comment: i think this might help:http://askubuntu.com/questions/386252/many-usb-multimedia-keyboard-issues-in-ubuntu-13-10

Comment: This is probably the worst suggestion i've ever seen on stackexchange.